# npm package installed in unexpected location

Tags: node.js, npm

I recently created [my first npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pre-commit-lint), and when I tried to install it on a computer running macOS using `npm install -g pre-commit-lint` I get the following output:

`/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node/lib/node_modules/node/lib/node_modules/node/lib/node_modules/node/lib/node_modules/node/lib/node_modules/node/lib/node_modules/node/bin/pc-lint -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/node/lib/node_modules/node/lib/node_modules/node/lib/node_modules/node/lib/node_modules/node/lib/node_modules/node/lib/node_modules/node/lib/node_modules/pre-commit-lint/index.js
+ pre-commit-lint@1.0.1
updated 1 package in 1.457s`

The install location is very unexpected to me.

Why would my package be installed in:

`/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node/lib/node_modules/node/lib/node_modules/node/lib/node_modules/node/lib/node_modules/node/lib/node_modules/node/lib/node_modules/node/lib/node_modules/`

instead of:

`/usr/local/lib/node_modules/`

Comment: Weird. Nothing wrong (installation-wise) with your module though, it installs correctly on my Mac. What does your `npm root` say?

Comment: Perhaps more specifically... what does running [`npm root -g`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/root.html) say?

Comment: @RobC the output of `npm root -g` is `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node/lib/node_modules/node/lib/node_modules/node/lib/node_modules/node/lib/node_modules/node/lib/node_modules/node/lib/node_modules/node/lib/node_modules` haha! I guess that explains _why_ the path is set that way, but doesn't explain how it got set to such a crazy path. I think I can figure out how to override that path, but it is very strange...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After further research, I found the `npm config ls -l` command, and in it's output, I found this line:

`prefix = "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node/lib/node_modules/node/lib/node_modules/node/lib/node_modules/node/lib/node_modules/node/lib/node_modules/node/lib/node_modules/node"`

This appears to be what is responsible for the weird path.

How this default got set, I have no idea. My co-worker's Mac had `prefix` set as `/usr/local` as did my home linux laptop. According to the [npm docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/folders#prefix-configuration), this is the default on most systems. I probably messed something up inadvertently in the early days of my work laptop.

To fix the issue, I ran the following command to override the default `prefix` value:

`npm config set prefix "/usr/local"`

I then uninstalled and reinstalled my package, and the binary appeared in:

```
/usr/local/bin/
```

Instead of:

`/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node/lib/node_modules/node/lib/node_modules/node/lib/node_modules/node/lib/node_modules/node/lib/node_modules/node/lib/node_modules/node/bin/`

And everything is working as expected now.